# Resizing font size in textarea to fit height

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do something different than most 'resize' textarea plugins do.  I am not trying to resize the actual textarea, but rather the font size in the textarea so that all of the text fits.

I basically want an 'auto' font size for a textarea.  The problem lies in the fact that there are two different ways that the font needs to get 'smaller':

1. User presses 'enter' and creates a line break
2. User enters more text than the width of the textarea, causing it to break down

I've seen a few instances of plugins which I've modified that creates a cloned textarea or div with the same styles that you can try to measure the new 'height' and calculate a font size based on this, but it seems to always fail in Safari and Chrome, so I'm guessing the logic is a bit flawed.

Has anybody done this before or know of a plugin where it has been done?

Comment: I've never seen this successfully done without using monospaced fonts that allow you to accurately predict text size. A pretty large limitation.

Answer (score 5):

Try this it should work but I'm not sure about performance tho:

**html**

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

**css**

```
textarea {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('textarea').keypress(function(){
    if ( $(this).get(0).scrollHeight > $(this).height() ) {
        $(this).css('font-size', '-=1');
    }
});
```

**example**

http://jsfiddle.net/XCXJb/1/

Comment: What if I remove some text? it should increase font size

Comment: Well, you can figure that out. This should put you in the right path. No need to vote down on a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: Actually I +1 but thought  that once get full solution will give +1 but anyways +1 without full solution :)

Comment: That's definitely on the right path, but decreasing the font size is a bit more difficult.  ScrollHeight is still returning the height of 100.  Will the string have to be measured for this?  If so, this may be difficult.

Comment: I am not able to +1 as I vote down, can you please update answer to I can vote up. sorry :(

Comment: @ncyankee, yup, it might get complicated. I'm thinking you can store the length of the string in an array whenever the font gets smaller and then reverse the behavior by counting characters on `e.keyCode === 8` and testing against the previously stored values to increase the `font-size` when it matches...Just an idea

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `textarea`, you could use a `div` with `contenteditable="true"`.
 This solution works with removing text and increasing the font-size.

**html**

```
<div class="border" id="border">
<div class="block" id="input" contenteditable="true">Click to edit</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.block {
    width:400px;
    font-size:25px;
    font-family:'Helvetica';
}
.block:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.border {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:400px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor:text;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#border').click(function(){
    $('#input').focus();
});

$('#input').keyup(function(event){
    while ( $(this).height() > 200) {
        $(this).css('font-size', '-=1');
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46) {
        while ( $(this).height() <= 200 && $(this).css('font-size') <= "25px") {
            $(this).css('font-size', '+=1');
        }
            $(this).css('font-size', '-=1');
    }
});
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/gwyqsk0s/