# Make font-size smaller in a fixed-size table row

Tags: javascript, html-table, font-size

I have a webpage with a `table` of dimensions `width: 8cm` and `height: 15.4cm`. The table consists of seven rows, each with the same height. Some rows will be filled with short text, and some with longer text, lasting 2-3 sentences.

Since I don't know before-hand how long the text would be, I want to let the browser choose the right font size to fit the text nicely in the table cell.

My webpage final destination is to be printed on a physical paper and therefore is not going to be viewed on various devices, so responsive approach is not the issue here.

After the conversation in the comments, I understand that the approach for this should be a javascript and not css. Can anyone explain how to do that?

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
        body {
            width:10cm;
            height: 16.8cm;
            border: 1px solid;
            margin: auto;}
        table {border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;} /* table with size of body */
        tr {border: 1px solid;
        height: calc(16.8cm/7); /* Distribute rows height */
            }
      </style>
  </head>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Some short text. Choose default font size for this row.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some longer text that I want its font-size to be smaller. How to do that? Blah blah blah asdf qwer zxcv. Some additional dummy text: Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text number 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text number 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text number 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text number 7</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is here:

[image: table]

Comment: I don't see why you think that those mentioned approaches work perfectly (for what you want to achieve), as none of those consider the text length.  I don't see how their approach would solve your problem even if you would consider one table cell as a viewport.

Comment: `But what are maximum viewport width and minimum viewport width in this case?` Instead of `px` you would use `cm` or `in` with the value that represents the target paper size. But as I said those approaches don't care about the text length and due to that won't help you with your problem.

Comment: I am not quite sure. I checked the computed font-size in the first eample [here](https://www.madebymike.com.au/writing/fluid-type-calc-examples/) and the it does changes almost continuously together with the browser width. And no length counting is involved.

Comment: What that css does is to set a base size for the font of an element and shrinks/scales that font size based on the current size of viewport. But if the size of the viewport stays the same and you only change the amount of text the font size stays the same. The base font size of a particular element is manually choosen.

Comment: I understand. Could you suggest an alternative for me?

Comment: Sorry afaik there is no css only solution for that. At least none I am currently aware of. (If there is one it is likely in a draft or not yet supported)

Comment: and a js solution?

Comment: I edited the original question

Comment: Take a look at this: [Resizing font size in textarea to fit height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205452/resizing-font-size-in-textarea-to-fit-height)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then this solution may be able to help you. This is not the most beautiful and optimal solution - but it seems to work:

```js
function normalize({
  table,
  maxFontSize = 40,
  stepFontSize = 0.5
}) {
  table.style.visibility = "hidden"; // hiding unpleasant visual effects
  const cells = table.querySelectorAll('td');
  cells.forEach((el) => {
    el.innerHTML = `<div class="container"><div class="wrapper">${el.innerHTML}</div></div>`;
    const container = el.querySelector('.container');
    const wrapper = el.querySelector('.wrapper');
    for (let i = maxFontSize; i > 0 && container.offsetHeight <= wrapper.offsetHeight; i -= stepFontSize) {
      el.style.fontSize = `${i}px`;
    }
    el.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML;
  });
  table.style.removeProperty('visibility');
}

normalize({
  table: document.querySelector('table')
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 10cm;
  height: 16.8cm;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}


/* table with size of body */

tr td {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: calc(16.8cm / 7);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Distribute rows height */
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some short text. Choose default font size for this row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some longer text that I want its font-size to be smaller. How to do that? Blah blah blah asdf qwer zxcv. Some additional dummy text: Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some longer text that I want its font-size to be smaller. How to do that? Blah blah blah asdf qwer zxcv. Some additional dummy text: Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Some
        longer text that I want its font-size to be smaller. How to do that? Blah blah blah asdf qwer zxcv. Some additional dummy text: Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text number 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text number 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text number 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text number 7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How it works:

- With the help of JS, we wrap the content of each cell in two `div` (outer - `.container`, and inner - `.wrapper`). The outer `div` with `overflow: hidden` shows the actual size of the cell, and the inner div shows the actual size of the content.
- We reduce the `font-size` and thereby reduce the size of the content until the internal `div` is smaller than the external one.
- In the end, we remove these `div` as unnecessary.

Two changes have been added to CSS:

1. added styles of the `.container` class for the above JS script.
2. `box-sizing: border-box`; has been added to the table cells, because when you use such a `height: calc(16.8cm / 7)` construction, you also need to take into account the padding value and the border thickness.

Comment: Nice! You have added a css rule to the `container` class. Is it taken into account anywhere in the html code? I do see it in the js one.

Comment: @tush, I have updated the answer by adding a bit of explanation.
The `.container` class is used only in the JS script, for correctly wrapping the cell content with an external block in order to correctly calculate their sizes.
These are just examples, if desired, you can rename all class names (both in CSS and in JS) as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the text size via Javascript until height matches your preferred height.

Comment: I am a javascript novice, can you elaborate?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).